# Can i ignore the 2 12volt dimmer wires on a new HIGH BAY LED, if i have an LED dimmer switch on the wall?

Tags: led

My LED light, is from H.D. It is a Commercial Electric brand. 2ft. linear high Bay Light. When I take off the power supply box cover, ( access to hook-up wiring), I find the line, load, and grnd wires, and two other wires. A small gray and a small purple wire. These are for a 0-10v dimming circuit,(according to the supplied booklet) if available. So the BIG question is, If I put in a Lutron  LED dimmer (ON/OFF with slider dimmer),switch, can I use this to control /dim the same LED light fixture?

Comment: what two additional wires are you talking about? ... what box did you open?

Comment: There are some lights that use low voltage controls to handle dimming, unlike "ordinary" lights. It sounds like your dimmer switch is "ordinary" and your lights are low voltage. **Model #s of the lights and the switch** would help us figure it out.

Comment: will have to get numbers and data for you tomorrow morning. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, we'll need make/model info for the fixtures in order to help you

Comment: Are you sure they are 12v? Most low-voltage-dimming fixtures I've seen are 0-10v on the dimming wires.

Comment: Are these purple and gray wires?  There are many dimming methods, various lights only work with certain ones.  If it offers 0-10V dimming it won't support a triac dimmer like Lutron.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dimming an LED HIGH BAY LIGHT FIXTURE](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/241817/dimming-an-led-high-bay-light-fixture)

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to read the instructions to confirm, but yes those two wires are likely for dimming. It is, in my opinion, a much superior dimming method compared to the voltage chopping techniques used in many familiar residential dimmers.

Then, simply return the dimmer you have and get another designed to work with the fixture's dimming scheme. The WSX D "Sensor Switch" by Acuity Controls is but one example of a 0-10v dimming control that may work with this fixture. These tend to be found in commercial jobs, so you may have to shop an electrical supply house rather than big box retail to find it.

Comment: You should be able to find a [WSX D at HD](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Lithonia-Lighting-Single-Pole-Dual-Detection-Wall-Switch-Occupancy-Sensor-with-Dimming-White-WSX-PDT-D-WH/301826792) though you may have to wait for it. They're also at [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/Lithonia-Lighting-WSX-PDT-D-WH-Occupancy-SwitchTM/dp/B076L9KFBV) for significantly less. You can safely ignore the 3-star review at HD - that user didn't have 0-10V dimming light fixtures ... and full disclosure: I work for Acuity and know the engineer who wrote the firmware for that switch - he's very thorough ;)

Answer (score 2):

### You can't use two different dimming methods.

Those lights say "dimmable" on the box.  But they use a dimming scheme known as "0-10V" *which is incompatible with* the bog-standard residential dimming scheme of triac dimming (leading edge or trailing edge).

So the lights will work but will treat the dimming as a brown-out, and do whatever they do, which won't be "dimming in an orderly fashion".

Yes, Home Depot has purchasing agents in China who find factories willing to make products for their "Commercial Electric" house-brand.  At least one of those suppliers is really in love with providing 0-10V dimming *instead of* triac dimming, probably because it is cheaper to make.

I realize many Americans have enduring love with the "big-box store" business model, but in the last decade that model has failed, with cheap-from-China "house brands" and price gouging on less popular items.

0-10V dimming is actually a *commercial* dimming method originally designed for fluorescent lights with modern electronic ballasts (yes they are dimmable). 0-10V is also designed to allow one dimmer to control lights on different *circuits* or even different *services*, which you might have in a large commercial installation like a mall.  *All the 0-10V kit is designed for architects who don't blink an eye at a $400 fixture or a $90 dimmer or all the extra wiring needed.*

Why don't commercial firms just stick with triac dimming" like homes use?  Because it doesn't play well with fluorescent or really, LED, for reasons I won't deep-dive into today.

---

Anyway... For Home Depot house brands, all they want is a "Dimmable" marketing claim. They don't care if it's unworkable for you and your project fails... they know statistically, you're not likely to return it, so you'll just buy other lights, probably from them.

So my recommendation is unprintable, but involves returning the product to HD with extreme prejudice and avoiding their house brand in the future.  If you want "triac-dimmable" LEDs, those are readily available from less crooked suppliers.  They're not as *high end, bespoke* as 0-10V dimming, but I don't gather "high-end" is what you're after today.

If you're all-in on 0-10V dimming, you will need to run an extra set of cables from the dimmer to each light.  (upside: the lights can be on different circuits).  This needs to also be AC mains rated cable, since it will be in the same boxes with AC mains power.

On most fixtures you can also just not hook the "dim" terminals to anything; in that case they should fix at full brightness.

Comment: I've learned the hard way about Commercial Electric. But I've also learned that Home Depot is really, really good on returns - whether broken (some of the Commercial Electric stuff I got that failed way too early) or unwanted (I bought some power tools I thought I would need but didn't, I had no problem returning, though if I had opened the box (in which case I know they'd be losing money taking it back unable to sell at full price) I wouldn't have returned them) or unneeded (I've walked in unsure of the size of some plumbing parts - HD employees told me to buy both and return the extra).

Comment: @manassehkatz Yes, I only meant to say consumers rarely *bother* pursuing returns, and that is the reason Home Depot can afford to be generous as you say.  Anyway, Home Depot contractually requires their suppliers to "eat" all returns, so even the customer service desk is a profit center to them.

Comment: Even if HD/Lowes were to eat the cost of returns, the supposition is that the return would lose them money. I doubt they're losing money, even on those returned items...

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't try to run LED lamps from a dimmer unless they are specifically designed to be dimmable.  This one is dimmable, but only using the two control wires.

If you try to run the lamp from a dimmer supply, it may not dim properly, it may flicker, and it could overheat and burn out.