# Dimming an LED HIGH BAY LIGHT FIXTURE

Tags: lighting, led

My LED light, is from H.D. It is a Commercial Electric brand. 2ft. linear high Bay Light. When I take off the power supply box cover, ( access to hook-up wiring), I find the line, load, and grnd wires, and two other wires. A small gray and a small purple wire. These are for a 0-10v dimming circuit,(according to the supplied booklet) if available. So the BIG question is, If I put in a Lutron  LED dimmer (ON/OFF with slider dimmer),switch, can I use this to control /dim the same LED light fixture?

Comment: Duplicate of  [Can i ignore the 2 12volt dimmer wires on a new HIGH BAY LED, if i have an LED dimmer switch on the wall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/241790/can-i-ignore-the-2-12volt-dimmer-wires-on-a-new-high-bay-led-if-i-have-an-led-d)

Comment: I VTC'd this one because the other one already had an answer.  However this version of the question is much better formed, so I copied its text to the other one. OP: be aware that you can edit a question yourself, and that is how to handle improvements, not posting dup questions.